# Azure Stream Analytics Job - Cumulative sum in fixed 1 hour window

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I'm currently working on a requirement for a real-time dashboard using steam analytics with a power bi output. The user would like to see a cumulative sum of an amount for the current hour. This would revert back to 0 at the beginning of the next hour.

From my understanding a Tumbling window should do this but the value doesn't change in the Power BI dashboard.

Any help would be appreciated!

Example:

```
SELECT System.Timestamp AS Timestamp,
   SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
INTO [TotalRevenuePerHour]
FROM [Input]
GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(hour,1)
```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? Maybe i miss your message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reponse but sorry, no. The hopping window just gives a moving aggregation e.g. 1 hour period, event 1 minute. What I'm looking for is a cumulative aggregation within the current hour. So in the current out the counter increases until the next hour where it would start again.

Comment: The tumbling window of 1 hour would calculate the query and send the Revenue value only at the end of the hour..so in powerbi you would see it change only at the end/begining of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding of your requirements,you want to sum some value every one hour.And the value need to be refreshed in real-time during this one hour. If my words is right,i think your direction is right. However, you could know about [Hopping Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/hopping-window-azure-stream-analytics), not Tumbling Windows.

You could get know about differences between them with below two pictures:

***Hopping Windows***

[image]

***Tumbling Windows***

[image]

Actually,tumbling window is simply a hopping window whose ‘hop’ is equal to its ‘size’.

Please see the example of Hopping Windows from above link:

```
SELECT System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd, TollId, COUNT(*)  
FROM Input TIMESTAMP BY EntryTime  
GROUP BY TollId, HoppingWindow(Duration(hour, 1), Hop(minute, 5), Offset(millisecond, -1))
```